# Simplicial set morphisms from an inner horn to a nerve are determined on the spine

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

This is a subject I'm completely new to, so I am a bit wary of my own proofs.

I will follow the notations of [Charles Rezk, *Stuff about
quasicategories*](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rezk/quasicats.pdf), as [of 5 April 2020](http://web.archive.org/web/20200405080427/https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rezk/quasicats.pdf). I want to prove the
following fact, which is an auxiliary observation in his proof of Proposition 5.9:

> **Lemma 5.9a.** Let $C$ be a category, and let $NC$ be its nerve. Let
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $0<j<n$. Consider the
>   inclusion $I^{n}\subseteq\Lambda_{j}^{n}$ of the spine of $\Delta^{n}$ into
>   the $j$-th inner horn $\Lambda_{j}^{n}$. Then, the canonical restriction map
>   $r:\operatorname*{Hom}\left(  \Lambda_{j}^{n},NC\right)  \rightarrow
> \operatorname*{Hom}\left(  I^{n},NC\right)  $ is bijective. (Here,
>   $\operatorname*{Hom}$ means morphisms of simplicial sets.)

I've so far been scared off Rezk's proof, partly because I don't understand
the meaning of $I^{S}$ when $S$ is not an interval. [**EDIT:** Charles has explained to me what $I^S$ means. Namely, if $S$ is a finite nonempty set of integers, then $I^S$ is the subcomplex of $\Delta^S$ generated by all the $0$-simplices and the $1$-simplices $i_0 i_1, i_1 i_2, \ldots, i_{k-1} i_k$, where $S$ is written in the form $S = \left\{ i_0 < i_1 < \cdots < i_k \right\}$. Equivalently, if we let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $S \cong \left[m\right]$, then $I^S$ is the image of $I^{\left[m\right]}$ under the canonical isomorphism $\Delta^{\left[m\right]} \to \Delta^S$.]
But mainly, I wanted to
see whether I could prove one of these things in a pedestrian, combinatorial way.

> **Question.** Is the following proof correct?

*Proof of Lemma 5.9a.* We shall only prove that $r$ is injective, since the
surjectivity of $r$ follows from Proposition 3.19 *op. cit.*.

This is obvious in the case when $n\leq2$ (because in this case, we
necessarily have $n=2$ and $j=1$, and thus $\Lambda_{j}^{n}=\Lambda_{1}
^{2}=I^{2}=I^{n}$). Thus, we WLOG assume that $n>2$. Hence, $n\geq3$.

Let $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ be two elements of $\operatorname*{Hom}\left(
\Lambda_{j}^{n},NC\right)  $ such that $r\left(  f\right)  =r\left(
f^{\prime}\right)  $. We must prove that $f=f^{\prime}$.

The morphisms $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ are simplicial set morphisms from
$\Lambda_{j}^{n}$ to $NC$, and they are equal when restricted to the
subcomplex $I^{n}$ of $\Lambda_{j}^{n}$ (since $r\left(  f\right)  =r\left(
f^{\prime}\right)  $).

Let $Z$ be the equalizer of $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ in the category of simplicial
sets. This is simply the subcomplex of $\Lambda_{j}^{n}$ given by
\begin{equation}
Z_{k}=\left\{  z\in\left(  \Lambda_{j}^{n}\right)  _{k}\ \mid\ f\left(
z\right)  =f^{\prime}\left(  z\right)  \right\}  \qquad\text{for each }
k\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}
Then, $I^{n}\subseteq Z$ (since $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ are equal when restricted
to the subcomplex $I^{n}$). Thus, $\left(  I^{n}\right)  _{0}\subseteq Z_{0}$
and $\left(  I^{n}\right)  _{1}\subseteq Z_{1}$.

If $S$ is a simplicial set, then I shall use the notation "$s\in S$" (or "$s$
belongs to $S$") as a shorthand for "$s\in S_{k}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$".

> *Claim 1:* Let $g\in\mathbb{N}$ and $z\in\left(  \Lambda_{j}^{n}\right)  _{g}
> $. Assume that
>   \begin{equation}
> z\left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle \in Z_{1}\qquad\text{for each }k\in\left\{
> 0,1,\ldots,g-1\right\}  .
> \end{equation}
>   Then, $z\in Z_{g}$.

*Proof of Claim 1:* If $g=0$, then this follows immediately from $z\in\left(
\Lambda_{j}^{n}\right)  _{g}=\left(  \Lambda_{j}^{n}\right)  _{0}=\left(
I^{n}\right)  _{0}\subseteq Z_{0}=Z_{g}$. Thus, WLOG assume that $g\neq0$.

Let $k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,g-1\right\}  $. Then, $z\left\langle
k,k+1\right\rangle \in Z_{1}$ (by assumption). In other words, $f\left(
z\left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle \right)  =f^{\prime}\left(  z\left\langle
k,k+1\right\rangle \right)  $ (by the definition of $Z$). But $f\left(
z\left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle \right)  =f\left(  z\right)  \left\langle
k,k+1\right\rangle $ (since $f$ is a morphism of simplicial sets) and
similarly $f^{\prime}\left(  z\left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle \right)
=f^{\prime}\left(  z\right)  \left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle $. Thus,
$f\left(  z\right)  \left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle =f\left(  z\left\langle
k,k+1\right\rangle \right)  =f^{\prime}\left(  z\left\langle
k,k+1\right\rangle \right)  =f^{\prime}\left(  z\right)  \left\langle
k,k+1\right\rangle $.

Now, forget that we fixed $k$. We thus know that each $k\in\left\{
0,1,\ldots,g-1\right\}  $ satisfies $f\left(  z\right)  \left\langle
k,k+1\right\rangle =f^{\prime}\left(  z\right)  \left\langle
k,k+1\right\rangle $. But a $g$-simplex $w$ in $NC$ is uniquely determined by
its edges $w\left\langle 0,1\right\rangle ,w\left\langle 1,2\right\rangle
,\ldots,w\left\langle g-1,g\right\rangle $ (since it just "consists" of
objects and morphisms of $C$, and these latter morphisms are precisely
$w\left\langle 0,1\right\rangle ,w\left\langle 1,2\right\rangle ,\ldots
,w\left\langle g-1,g\right\rangle $, whereas the objects are uniquely
determined by the morphisms (here we use $g\neq0$)). In other words, if $w$
and $w^{\prime}$ are two $g$-simplices in $NC$ such that each $k\in\left\{
0,1,\ldots,g-1\right\}  $ satisfies $w\left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle
=w^{\prime}\left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle $, then $w=w^{\prime}$. Applying
this to $w=f\left(  z\right)  $ and $w^{\prime}=f^{\prime}\left(  z\right)  $,
we conclude that $f\left(  z\right)  =f^{\prime}\left(  z\right)  $. In other
words, $z\in Z_{g}$ (by the definition of $Z$). This proves Claim 1.

Next, let us recall that the elements of $\left(  \Lambda_{j}^{n}\right)
_{g}$ for a given $g\in\mathbb{N}$ are the simplicial operators $\left[
g\right]  \rightarrow\left[  n\right]  $ whose image does not contain $\left[
n\right]  \setminus\left\{  j\right\}  $ as a subset (where, as usual,
$\left[  n\right]  =\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  $). In other words, they
are the simplicial operators $\left[  g\right]  \rightarrow\left[  n\right]  $
which miss at least one element distinct from $j$.

> *Claim 2:* Let $p$ and $q$ be integers satisfying $0\leq p\leq q\leq n$ and
>   $\left(  p,q\right)  \neq\left(  0,n\right)  $. Then, the morphism
>   $\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots,q\right\rangle :\left[  q-p\right]  \rightarrow
> \left[  n\right]  $ belongs to $Z$.

*Proof of Claim 2:* The image of the morphism $\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots
,q\right\rangle $ does not contain $\left[  n\right]  \setminus\left\{
j\right\}  $ as a subset (since otherwise, it would contain both $0$ and $n$
(since $0<j<n$), but this would contradict $\left(  p,q\right)  \neq\left(
0,n\right)  $). Hence, $\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots,q\right\rangle \in\left(
\Lambda_{j}^{n}\right)  _{q-p}$. For each $k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots
,q-p-1\right\}  $, we have
\begin{equation}
\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots,q\right\rangle \left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle
=\left\langle p+k,p+k+1\right\rangle \in\left(  I^{n}\right)  _{1}\subseteq
Z_{1}.
\end{equation}
Hence, Claim 1 (applied to $g=q-p$ and $z=\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots
,q\right\rangle $) shows that $\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots,q\right\rangle \in
Z_{q-p}$. This proves Claim 2.

> *Claim 3:* Let $p$ and $q$ be integers satisfying $0\leq p\leq q\leq n$ and
>   $\left(  p,q\right)  \neq\left(  0,n\right)  $. Then, the morphism
>   $\left\langle p,q\right\rangle :\left[  1\right]  \rightarrow\left[  n\right]
> $  belongs to $Z$.

*Proof of Claim 3:* Claim 2 yields that $\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots
,q\right\rangle $ belongs to $Z$. Thus, $\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots
,q\right\rangle \left\langle 0,q-p\right\rangle $ also belongs to $Z$ (since
$Z$ is a simplicial set). In view of $\left\langle p,p+1,\ldots,q\right\rangle
\left\langle 0,q-p\right\rangle =\left\langle p,q\right\rangle $, this
rewrites as follows: The morphism $\left\langle p,q\right\rangle :\left[
1\right]  \rightarrow\left[  n\right]  $ belongs to $Z$. This proves Claim 3.

> *Claim 4:* Let $p$ and $q$ be integers satisfying $0\leq p\leq q\leq n$. Then,
>   the morphism $\left\langle p,q\right\rangle :\left[  1\right]  \rightarrow
> \left[  n\right]  $ belongs to $Z$.

*Proof of Claim 4:* If $\left(  p,q\right)  \neq\left(  0,n\right)  $, then
this follows from Claim 3. Hence, we WLOG assume that $\left(  p,q\right)
=\left(  0,n\right)  $. Thus, $\left\langle p,q\right\rangle =\left\langle
0,n\right\rangle $.

We have $n\geq3$. Hence, the image of the morphism $\left\langle
0,j,n\right\rangle :\left[  2\right]  \rightarrow\left[  n\right]  $ does not
contain $\left[  n\right]  \setminus\left\{  j\right\}  $ as a subset (since
it contains only $2$ elements of $\left[  n\right]  \setminus\left\{
j\right\}  $). Hence, $\left\langle 0,j,n\right\rangle \in\left(  \Lambda
_{j}^{n}\right)  _{2}$. Moreover, $\left\langle 0,j,n\right\rangle
\left\langle 0,1\right\rangle =\left\langle 0,j\right\rangle $ belongs to $Z$
(by Claim 2, applied to $\left(  p,q\right)  =\left(  0,j\right)  $), so that
$\left\langle 0,j,n\right\rangle \left\langle 0,1\right\rangle \in Z_{1}$.
Similarly, $\left\langle 0,j,n\right\rangle \left\langle 1,2\right\rangle \in
Z_{1}$. Combining these two results, we conclude that $\left\langle
0,j,n\right\rangle \left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle \in Z_{1}$ for each
$k\in\left\{  0,1\right\}  $. Thus, Claim 1 (applied to $g=2$ and
$z=\left\langle 0,j,n\right\rangle $) shows that $\left\langle
0,j,n\right\rangle \in Z_{2}$. Hence, $\left\langle 0,j,n\right\rangle
\left\langle 0,2\right\rangle \in Z_{1}$ (since $Z$ is a subcomplex).
In view of $\left\langle 0,j,n\right\rangle \left\langle 0,2\right\rangle
=\left\langle 0,n\right\rangle =\left\langle p,q\right\rangle $, this rewrites
as $\left\langle p,q\right\rangle \in Z_{1}$. This proves Claim 4.

> *Claim 5:* We have $f\left(  z\right)  =f^{\prime}\left(  z\right)  $ for each
>   $z\in\Lambda_{j}^{n}$.

*Proof of Claim 5:* Fix $z\in\Lambda_{j}^{n}$. Thus, $z\in\left(  \Lambda
_{j}^{n}\right)  _{g}$ for some $g\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider this $g$.

Claim 4 shows that $\left(  \Lambda_{j}^{n}\right)  _{1}\subseteq Z_{1}$. But
$z\in\Lambda_{j}^{n}$. Since $\Lambda_{j}^{n}$ is a simplicial set, we thus have

\begin{equation}
z\left\langle k,k+1\right\rangle \in\left(  \Lambda_{j}^{n}\right)
_{1}\subseteq Z_{1}\qquad\text{for each }k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,g-1\right\}
.
\end{equation}
Thus, $z\in Z_{g}$ (by Claim 1). In view of the definition of $Z$, this yields
$f\left(  z\right)  =f^{\prime}\left(  z\right)  $. This proves Claim 5.

Clearly, Claim 5 proves that $f=f^{\prime}$. This proves Lemma 5.9a.